# Why does Jenkins not use the default rails installed by Amazon EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration, amazon-ec2, jenkins

I am trying to setup a continuous integration environment using Ubuntu VM on Amazon EC2 (which has rails installed already) and Jenkins. But Jenkins creates its own user on the VM and cannot find the rails path because its in the other user's environment.

So can someone provide me a step by step installation guideline for the same.

Thanks